# Django Admin - Bulk editing data?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Are there any admin extensions to let bulk editing data in Django Admin? (ie. Changing the *picture* fields of all *product* models at once. Note that this is needed for a users POV so scripting doesn't count.) Any thoughts on subject welcome.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With Django 1.1, you can create admin actions which can be applied to multiple entries at once. See [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#ref-contrib-admin-actions) on this subject.

Comment: Oh I was afraid this was going to be the only answer but still it's better than rolling a custom app. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[Django "Mass Change" Admin Site Extension](https://github.com/burke-software/django-mass-edit).

Comment: The original blog seems to have disappeared. I've improved and posted it [here](http://code.google.com/p/django-mass-edit/)

Answer (score -3):

You have SQL.  You can write SQL UPDATE statements.

You have Python for writing batch scripts that interact with the Django ORM.  This works really, really well for bulk changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer S.Lott. I wish I could say that to the client though :-)

Comment: Why can't you?  Our application involves numerous bulk updates done as batch jobs -- Pythons scripts that use the ORM.

Comment: My clients IT is run by average Joe's. They can't possibly be bothered with SQL. Yet bulk editing is a requirement for the project. Hopefully Django 1.1 will come to the rescue.

Comment: We don't use SQL.  We use Python scripts using the Django ORM.  No SQL of any kind.  Just bulk load and extract applications that run from the command line.  Very simple.